# how to use logcat commands within java code?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, logcat

I want to use "adb logcat -d > C:\Users\lenovo 01\Documents\android\sdk\platform-tools" command line command within my java code. this works directly in command prompt but it doesn't work within java code.
for example:

```
pb = new ProcessBuilder("adb", "logcat", "-d", ">", "C:\\android\\cellograf.txt");
pc = pb.start();
pc.waitFor();       
System.out.println("written");
```

when I execute this, nothing happens. It writes only "written" but the file is empty. When I run this command in command prompt, it works correctly and writes all logcat output to that file. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirecting output to a file is a feature of the command interpeter; it's not something that can be performed by the process itself. Try appending `cmd /c` to the beginning of your command:

```
pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", "adb", "logcat", "-d", ">", "C:\\android\\cellograf.txt");
```

Comment: Yes, This worked very well. Thank you very much yole!

Comment: How about Linux system? I face with the same situation but I am using Linux operation system.